# Issue in understanding the Spark MLlib's LinearRegressionWithSGD example in python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

So, I am a rookie to `machine learning` and `Spark` and was going through Spark `MLlibs` documentation on `Regression` especially `LinearRegressionWithSGD` at [this page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#linear-least-squares-lasso-and-ridge-regression). I am having a bit of difficulty in understanding the `python` code. Here iss what I have understood so far - The code loads the data and then forms `labeledpoint`. After that the model is build and then it is  evaluated on the training data and `MSE` is calculated.

Now that part that is confusing me is that during the normal `machine learning` process we first divide the data into training set and test set.  The we build the model using training set and finally evaluate using test set. Now in the code at the Spark MLlib's documentation I do not see any division into training and test set. And on top of that I see them building the model using the data and then evaluating using the same data.

Is there something that I am not able to understand in the code? Any help to understand the code will be helpful.

**NOTE:** THis is the code at Spark MLlib's documentation page for `LinearRegressionWithSGD`

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint, LinearRegressionWithSGD, LinearRegressionModel

# Load and parse the data
def parsePoint(line):
    values = [float(x) for x in line.replace(',', ' ').split(' ')]
    return LabeledPoint(values[0], values[1:])

data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/ridge-data/lpsa.data")
parsedData = data.map(parsePoint)

# Build the model
model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData)

# Evaluate the model on training data
valuesAndPreds = parsedData.map(lambda p: (p.label, model.predict(p.features)))
MSE = valuesAndPreds.map(lambda (v, p): (v - p)**2).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y) / valuesAndPreds.count()
print("Mean Squared Error = " + str(MSE))

# Save and load model
model.save(sc, "myModelPath")
sameModel = LinearRegressionModel.load(sc, "myModelPath")
```

Comment: Well, they say that they evaluate on training data..

Comment: @hellpanderrr yes I see that they are evaluating on the training data but isn't that the wrong way? I mean the model is built on the training data then wouldn't the testing on the same data will give scripted outcome? Shouldn't the correct approach would have been to divide the data into two sets and then build the model on one and train on other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure you are talking about is cross-validation. As you observed, the example above didn't do cross-validation. But this doesn't mean it's wrong.

The sole purpose of that example is to illustrate how to train and use a model. You are free to split the data and cross-validate the model, the procedure will be the same. Only the data changed.

And in addition, **performance on training set is also valuable**. It can tell you whether your model is overfitter or underfitting.

So to summurize, the example is all right, what you need is another example on cross-validation.